# Header files don't see each other

Tags: c++

I have two classes named `Manager` and `Worker`. Each `Worker` has a `Manager` and each `Manager` has a `Worker` to manage.
I am defining the classes at separately header files.

manager.h

```
#include "worker.h"

class Manager{
    private:
        Worker* worker;
    public:
        /* methods etc */
};
```

worker.h

```
#include "manager.h"

class Worker{
    private:
        Manager* manager;
    public:
        /* methods etc */
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "worker.h"
#include "manager.h"

int main(void){
    /* code code */
}
```

Ok until now it seems to be everything ok, but when I try to compile it gives lots of lines with the names of the headers.
First I thought that it created a kind of loop and was including the headers endless. I then searched about it and tried to use `#ifndef #define #endif` in each header file. Turns out that now the problem is that the class Worker doesn't see the class Manager and vice-versa, meaning that the errors now are "'Worker' does not name a type" etc etc etc.

Comment: Look to the right. There are a number of questions that would give you the answer.

Comment: you have to declare one of them first, lets say `Worker`, but then at this point, the `Manager` is not declared yet. As the worker only needs a pointer to a manager (ie. he doesnt need to know the size of a `Manager` object) it is sufficient to supply a forward declaration at the top of the `Worker` header.

Comment: Also: [Resolve circular dependencies in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c)

Comment: Change `#include "worker.h"` to `class Worker;`. Ditto for manager